# Why is 'declval' specified in terms of 'add_rvalue_reference<T>::type' and not 'T&&'?

Tags: c++, c++11

`§20.2.4 [declval]`

```
template <class T>
typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept; // as unevaluated operand
```

Why use `add_rvalue_reference` here?

From `§20.9.7.2 [meta.trans.ref]` on `add_rvalue_reference`:

> If `T` names an object or function type then the member typedef `type` shall name `T&&`; otherwise, `type` shall name `T`. [ *Note:* This rule reflects the semantics of reference collapsing (8.3.2). For example, when a type `T` names a type `T1&`, the type `add_rvalue_reference<T>::type` is not an rvalue reference. *—end note* ]

Since `add_rvalue_reference` is meant to reflect reference collapsing anyways, why not just use `T&&` like the following?

```
template<class T>
T&& declval();
```

What could go wrong? What exactly are the differences between the two versions?

Comment: "What could possibly go wrong?" Duck!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Err.. what? Just because I overlooked something I'm getting -1? Interesting stuff...

Comment: @Lightness Now _that_ is pointless.

Comment: You didn't just overlook it. You quoted, verbatim, the answer to your question. You wanted to know how `T&&` differs from `add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`, then quoted the passage that shows you how the latter does a bit more than the former, telling you precisely what that something is and giving you an example of such a case. @Etienne: The Stack Overflow voting system is not "pointless".

Comment: @Lightness, that example exactly reflects how `T&&` also works - if `T` is a `T1&`, then `T&&` is `T1& &&`, which collapses back to `T1&`. As mentioned by Howard, the real difference (which is not explicitly mentioned in the Standard quote) is that `add_rvalue_reference` also works in case of `cv void`, whereas `void&&` is ill-formed.

Comment: @Xeo: I take it back then. Sorry!

Comment: @Lightness: Well, you were partially right. "If T names an object or function type" - `void` is not an object or function type, so...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if this is the actual reason, but `add_rvalue_reference` has different behavior for `void`.

`add_rvalue_reference<void>::type` is simply `void`.

`void&&` is an error.

Comment: Oooh, good point. However, when would you actually want a `std::declval<void>()`? I can only imagine in an expression SFINAE `decltype(t.size(), std::declval<void>(), std::true_type)` or something, but `void()` is much more convenient and works all the same.

Comment: @Xeo maybe in template classes that allow `void` as template param? `template<class T> class foo { … declval<T> … }; foo<void> bar;`. This might be rare, but it's better if it works when you don't need it, than if it doesn't work when you do need it.

Comment: I'll accept this, since it plainly states what I was missing / overlooking: "`void&&` is an error".

Comment: @Xeo:  Imagine a SFINAE involving a `declval<T>`.  Maybe the SFINAE "fails" for `T == void` but you want that failure to return false, not result in a compile-time error.  Having `declval<void>` not create a compile-time error is helpful in that endeavor.

Answer (score 11):

Several definitions depend upon `declval` giving reasonable results for *cv-qualified* `void`.  An example is `is_assignable`:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct is_assignable;
```

> The expression `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` is well-formed when treated
>   as an unevaluated operand ...

The intent is that "well-formed" refers to the well-formed-ness of the assignment expression, and not whether `declval<T>` itself is well-formed.  I.e. we want to worry about just one thing at a time.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that `add_rvalue_reference<>` only really adds the `&&` part if `T` is an object or function type. If `T` isn't an object or function type (e.g. `void`) you don't want to add `&&`.

See [this example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/as8Bi).
[This webpage of Boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/doc/html/declval.html) explains:

> The role of the function template `declval()` is a transformation of a type `T` into a value without using or evaluating this function. The name is supposed to direct the reader's attention to the fact that the expression `declval<T>()` is an lvalue if and only if `T` is an lvalue-reference, otherwise an rvalue. To extend the domain of this function we can do a bit better by changing its declaration to
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval(); // not used
> ```
>
> which ensures that we can also use cv `void` as template parameter.